# Find the equation of y[n] from the block diagram

Tags: z-transform

So we are given a block diagram and we have to find the y[n] "equation". The problem is i just dont get what that plus at the end does

Also i have "calculated" the equation but id like to see if its correct or not

[image: Picture of the graph]

what i found out is:

$x[n]z^{-1}+x[n]z^{-2}a+y[n]z^{-2}c+y[n]z^{-1}b=y[n]$

Is this correct? Also does that plus do anything?

Comment: As far as I can tell the plus sign does not do anything and is likely a mistake. You have the gist of it correctly but your notation is wrong. Multiplication with $z^{-1}$ would be correct in the frequency domain but not in the time domain. It's delay operator, so the correct notation  is $x[n-2]$ instead of $x[n]z^{-2}$

Comment: There’s also a mistake on that bottom branch… arrow facing the wrong way

Comment: I would ask the person responsible for the figure to fix it before you waste any of your time on it.

Comment: There's some abuse of notation going on here.  The use of $x[n]$ implies a sampled-time domain, while the use of $z^{-1}$ in blocks implies the $z$ domain.  Try replacing $x[n]$ with $X(z)$ and $y[n]$ with $Y(z)$.  Then see how your equation looks better, and _then_, see if you can solve it for $Y(z)$, or $Y(z)/X(z)$.